# php print current day plus to days

Tags: php, getdate

I think the question says it all. I am not sure how to get the currentdate + 2 days. here was my attempt

```
//insert invoice table
                $currentdate = getdate();
                $duedate = getdate() + 2000;
                $makeinvoice = mysql_query("INSERT INTO invoices (userid, hostid, price, ispaid, detecreated, duedate) VALUES ('$userid', '$prodid', '$initprice', '0', '$currentdate','$duedate' )",$conn);
```

Comment: i use it on mysql_query to insert the current date and time.

Comment: i think it has to be like that which will be inserted to the mysql datetime data

Comment: Well, there aren't 2 thousand of anything meaningful in two days, and [`getdate()`](http://php.net/getdate) returns an array, so this isn't much of an attempt. Have a look at [the many date functions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) and see if you can spot one more suited to the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

am assuming you want to get a unix timestamp. 
just use `strtotime('+ 2 days')`

EDIT

```
//insert invoice table
$currentdate = time();
$duedate = strtotime('+2 days');

$makeinvoice = mysql_query("INSERT INTO invoices (userid, hostid, price, ispaid, detecreated, duedate) VALUES ('$userid', '$prodid', '$initprice', '0', '$currentdate','$duedate' )",$conn);
```

P.S, you should use the `mysqli` extention as `mysql` is old and would be discontinued soon. Or better still, use `pdo`

Comment: @Gelo103097 hope it helped..:)

Answer (score 0):

This should return a timestamp 2 days ahead

```
$due_date = strtotime('+ 2 days');
```

Comment: [No it won't.](http://3v4l.org/n8jlZ) The reason being that `strtotime('+ 2 days')` *already* assumes you mean two days *from now*, not from the beginning of time, so adding it onto the current time will give you a very large timestamp, a lot more than two days in the future!